# NoSQL encourages designing database based on access patterns. What to do when the patterns change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

NoSQL encourages designing database based on access patterns and it can perform those queries it was designed for very fast. For other queries, the performance is not so good. But for software, change is the norm. So when new requirements come in and we have to add new features, how can nosql databases adapt? Or better yet, how can I design nosql databases(preferably dynamodb) that will allow me to adapt to new feature additions.

The first approach that comes to my mind will be to design a new table and migrate all the previous data to the new table. But considering the table has millions of records, its probably not very cost effective

References:

[Rick Houlihan talking about designing dynamodb table based on access patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k)

[Dynamodb design best practices from aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html)

Comment: why is this nosql different than sql(add a new column???) when access pattern changes? if you have not taken something into account you would have to do a migration.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is schema-less, so you can add a new attribute at any time without having to do any backfill or migration. Just make sure your application knows what to do if the attribute is not present.

If you need to query that attribute, you can add a new GSI on the attribute. DynamoDB has an initial quota of 20 GSIs per table, but you can request a quota increase if you need more.

If your new use case isn’t satisfied by a GSI, you can create a new table containing your new attribute(s) to use alongside the existing table. If you need a guarantee of consistency between those tables, you can use DynamoDB transactions to keep them in sync.

Answer (score 0):

One way to minimize full table migrations in order to adapt to new changes would be to use generic names for indexes. In the case of dynamodb, we would have pk as partition_key and sk for sort_key as well as all the attributes of the item. The value of pk and sk will actually be a derived value from other attributes. More importantly, we will add 5 LSIs during table creation and use them when necessary. For example, to store data about a book, a row in the table will have the following fields:
`pk, sk, ISBN, data_type, author, created_at, ...other data, lsi1, lsi2, lsi3, lsi4, lsi5`

The values for the fields: 
`pk->ISBN, sk->data_type, ISBN->ISBN, ...., lsi1->data_type#created_at , lsi(2-5)->empty`

This way, unless there are drastic changes in the requirements the table structure of our table is unlikely to change. One thing to note here is that unless an item that is added, deleted or updated contains an attribute that belongs to an index, no computational or storage cost is incurred in dynamodb.